# PHP - Eliminar caracter viñeta

Tags: php, string

estoy buscando la manera de eliminar el primer carácter cuando es una viñeta. Ejemplo:

```
$f = '• Esto es un ejemplo';
```

Es sencillo si es el primer carácter lo elimino con subtr y listo pero me interesa que únicamente lo elimine si es el carácter especial de viñeta con lo cual la cosa se complica.

Qué he hecho?:

```
if(substr($f, 0, 1) == '•'){                                    

   $f = substr($f, 1);
                                                                                    }
```

No funciona. He estado buscando en internet y no he encontrado mucha información.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: ¿Quieres reemplazar solamente la primera ocurrencia o todas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Opcion 1

Si necesitas eliminar **solo el primer caracter**, entonces podrías crear una expresión regular y utilizar [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php).

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php

$f = '• Esto es un ejemplo
 • Esto es otro ejemplo
 •    Esto es el ultimo ejemplo';
echo preg_replace('/•/', '', $f, 1);
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c167f4fe1cdb697d423227259fef2f6c7a76fee)</kbd>

### Opcion 2

Si necesitas eliminar todas las ocurrencias del caracter, entonces podrías usar [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php

$f = '• Esto es un ejemplo
• Esto es otro ejemplo
• Esto es el ultimo ejemplo';
echo str_replace('•', '', $f);
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83ea7f5f58964fac0a290fcd9c7f83bdffbfa0eb)</kbd>

---

En el caso que necesites eliminar además los espacios antes y/o después del caracter, entonces podrías hacerlo así:

```
<?php

$f = '• Esto es un ejemplo
 • Esto es otro ejemplo
 •    Esto es el ultimo ejemplo';
echo preg_replace('/ *• */', '', $f);
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/213e56335e59a103d42dfbc74ef0d2baccb91958)</kbd>

Comment: En caso que necesites eliminar el espacio en blanco entre la viñeta y el texto, debes agregar el espacio luego del •, así `echo preg_replace('[• ]', '', $f);`

Comment: No queda claro en la pregunta si quiere reemplazar todas las ocurrencias o solamente la primera. Si fuesen todas es mucho más simple usar `str_replace`, lo recomienda el mismo Manual de PHP, porque esta última trabaja más rápido que `preg_replace`. Si fuese sólo la primera ocurrencia, hay que poner un límite a `preg_replace`

Comment: Se puede modificar tu respuesta, si el OP aclara el requerimiento, para no tener dos respuestas que son casi parecidas.

Comment: @A.Cedano, actualice mi respuesta.

Comment: Gracias @Marcos funciona perfectamente la solución.

Answer (score 1):

Para ese tipo de caracteres tienes que usar mb_substr ([PHP: mb_substr - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)
)
Por ejemplo :

```
        $f = '• Esto es un ejemplo';

        if(mb_substr($f, 0, 1) == '•'){
           // ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para esto puedes usar la función [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php) de PHP, que te transformará el primer carácter al código HTML correspondiente. Luego sólo debes eliminarlo.

```
$f = htmlentities('• Esto es un ejemplo');
echo trim(str_replace("&bull;", "", $f));
```

Como ves, también he aplicado la función trim para eliminar el espacio en blanco que quedaría en el inicio del string. Pero también podrías usar esta función para reemplazar el carácter especial.

```
trim($f, "&bull; ");
```